# Static PDF URL link next to Picklist field

Tags: visualforce, configuration, customization

[image]I have a requirement where i want a static link/button next to custom picklist field(Standard Pagelayout - existing picklist field) which would open up a PDF file(Same window or New window).

I just wanted to know if this can be achieved with configuration or should i go for VF page.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. You need to give more context information to get an answer from the community. Can you please post some code snippet showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: I did not try any code. I just wanted to know if this can be achieved with configuration or should i go for VF page.

Comment: In that case, you should re-phrase your question by adding this detail.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this all you need to do is to go to the Object in which you want to add the Button with URL.

For this example I used Account:

> 1. Click on Setup-> Customize (under Build)-> Account -> Search Lauyouts-> Click on Edit left to 'Account List View'.
> 2. After that click on 'Click here to create a new custom list button'
> 3. Fill in all require fields and make sure you have URL under Content URL.
> 4. List Button needs to be selected.
> 5. Add you link to the PDF open area, Check Syntax, all good? save

That is all!

Comment: Hi Viasur, Thanks for you reply. My requirement is having a link/pdf next to picklist field. Please see the image added above. I have a long list of picklist value and i cannot put the help content of this values in help(SF provided field) so we have created a pdf which would explain about each pick list value and i need this very next to the picklist field. I hope you have some understanding on my requirement now..

Comment: Hello Saroj, do you absolutely need it to be there? There is a section on your page layout where you can add your links and customs buttons. I will suggest doing this as it is the fastest and easiest way. The other way is to use Visualforce and redesign that section, too much effort for just a link. So, let me know if it is totally necessary to have it there.